# Passing enum got org.joor.ReflectException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: field()

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I got error (org.joor.ReflectException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: service()) in passing enum in funcition like there was no field service. My enum is not static is this a problem? I dont really see problem in code. I have two enum class one take values from another one.

```
public enum Modules {CONNECTOR_CLIENT("E", "A", "C");
public final String section;
public final String service;
public final String module;

Modules(String service, String section, String module) {
    this.service = service;
    this.section = section;
    this.module = module;
}}


public enum ModuleData {CONNECTOR_CLIENT(Modules.CONNECTOR_CLIENT.get(), ModulesLinks.CONNECTOR_CLIENT.get(), ModuleLogs.CONNECTOR_CLIENT.get()),;

public final LinkedHashMap menuModules;
public final LinkedHashMap link;
public final Boolean oldModule;

ModuleData(LinkedHashMap menuModules, LinkedHashMap link, Boolean oldModule) {
    this.menuModules = menuModules;
    this.link = link;
    this.oldModule = oldModule;
}

public String module() {
    return menuModules.get("module").toString();
}

public String link() {
    return String.valueOf(link.get("link"));
}

public String service() {
    return menuModules.get("service").toString();
}

public String section() {
    return menuModules.get("section").toString();
}

public Boolean newModule() {
    return oldModule;
}}
```

Run in class

```
    @Step("({moduleData.service()}) ({moduleData.module()})")public void moveToModule(ModuleData moduleData, String browser) throws Exception {
    try {

        log.info(moduleData.service() + " " +
                moduleData.section() + " " +
                moduleData.module() + " " + moduleData.link());}}moveToModule(ModuleData.CONNECTOR_CLIENT, testSuite);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: coused by framework Allure and @Step annotanion.

Comment: Did you find out how to get `{moduleData.service()}` in @Step annotation?